# Returning the results of an integral as a function

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy, integral

I am trying to calculate the integral of a function where the results of another integral is implemented. It looks a bit like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

Formula_U=lambda t: 325 * np.sin(100 * np.pi * t -3)
Formula_I=lambda t: 100 * np.sin(100 * np.pi * t -3)

#To calculate:
Integral on [0,1] of ( Formula_I * INTEGRATED(Formula_U) )

Results = integrate.quad(Formula_I * ~~integrate.quad(Formula_U)~~ ,0,1)[0]
```

The part between the ~~...~~ doesn't work. I know integrate.quad doesn't support this, but I'm looking for something that returns the integrated formula "Formula_U" as a **formula** instead of a value, so the given integral can be calculated dynamically.

I've tried looking into other post, but I can't find anything on calculating the integral of a formula without limits. I've tried hardcoding the integral as a separate variable with lambda, but the input sine wave changes as soon as I add a few harmonic sine waves to the equation, so that's not an option.

I've tried doing something with sympy, but I don't know how to translate a string into a variable using lambda.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can define Formula_U as an object function instead of a lambda and pass it to integrate.quad

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure because I don't have experience with scipy integrate but I think you can try something along these lines :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

#Formula_U=lambda t: 325 * np.sin(100 * np.pi * t -3)
Formula_I=lambda t: 100 * np.sin(100 * np.pi * t -3)

def Formula_U(t)
    325 * np.sin(100 * np.pi * t -3)

#To calculate:
#Integral on [0,1] of ( Formula_I * INTEGRATED(Formula_U) )

Results = integrate.quad(Formula_I,Formula_U) ,0,1)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you intending to pass the lambda or an expression to integrate? If you define a lambda like `f = lambda x: 1 + cos(x)` if you write `f(2)` you will get `1 + cos(2)`; if you just write `f` you get the function itself, ready for something else to call, e.g. `g=f; g(2) == f(2)-->True`. Bypassing scipy and doing this in SymPy looks like this:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import t
>>> Formula_U=lambda t: 325 * sin(100 * pi * t -3)
>>> Formula_I=lambda t: 100 * sin(100 * pi * t -3)
>>> general = integrate(Formula_U(t))
>>> integrate(Formula_I(t) * general, (t,0,1))
0
```